# How to remove objects from unstructured json by key-value with play json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have many of unstructured jsons. For example:

```
{
  "peoples": [
    {
      "name": "Vasya",
      "age": 33
    },
    {
      "name": "Petya",
      "age": 40,
      "childs": [
        {
          "name": "Vasya",
          "age": 33
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "notPeoples": [
    {
      "name": "Vasya",
      "kind": "starship"
    },
     {
      "name": "Iq441",
      "kind": "car"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need remove all objects, where `name = "Vasya"`. Note, that it can be json with any schemas (not only peoples - any json where some objects have "name" field), so I should analyse every object(array in array etc).

Result should be:

```
{
  "peoples": [
    {
      "name": "Petya",
      "age": 40,
      "childs": []
    }
  ],
  "notPeoples": [
    {
      "name": "Iq441",
      "kind": "car"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to achive this with play json transformations? Or maybe with another java/scala libs.

Comment: You're going to have trouble with this if you just have randomly named fields ("peoples", "notPeoples", "foo", "bar", etc.) inside a JSON object. The libraries that I know of can't iterate over fields inside a JSON object -- rather, you iterate over JSON arrays. Is is there a reason why your top-level JSON object can't be an array instead?

Comment: In my case top level json can be any type.

Comment: @zella, can you post the solution in case it is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The example does not yield the exact JSON you posted but I guess you get the idea how to filter arbitrary JSON with `play.json`:

```
def filterByName(name: String, filter: JsValue, js: JsValue): JsValue = js match {
    case JsArray(vs) => JsArray(vs.map(filterByName(name, filter, _)))
    case JsObject(vs) =>
      JsObject(vs.flatMap { case (key, value) =>
          if (key == name && value == filter) None
          else Some(key -> filterByName(name, filter, value))
      })
    case otherwise => otherwise
  }

def filterByString(name: String, value: String, js: JsValue): JsValue =
  filterByName(name, JsString(value), js)
```

Edit:
If I understand your use case correctly you might implement your filter logic like the following - the example above filters single elements from the input JSON while this one filters the 'surrounding' objects in case one its elements satisfies the predicate:

```
def filterObjElements(name: String, value: JsValue, js: JsValue): JsValue = {
  def filter(current: JsValue): Option[JsValue] = current match {
    case JsArray(vs) => Some(JsArray(vs.flatMap(filter)))
    case JsObject(vs) =>
      if (vs.exists { case (key, value0) => key == name && value0 == value})
        None
      else {
        Some(JsObject(vs.flatMap { case (key, value0) =>
          filter(value0).map(key -> _)
        }))
      }
    case otherwise => Some(otherwise)
  }

  js match {
    case arr: JsArray => filter(arr).getOrElse(JsArray())
    case obj: JsObject => filter(obj).getOrElse(JsObject(Nil))
    case otherwise => otherwise
  }
}

def filterObjElements(name: String, value: String, js: JsValue): JsValue =
  filterObjElements(name, JsString(value), js)
```